# Custom Object Initialization does not store NSMutableArray objects with addObject:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, init

In creating a login screen with static logins I'm trying to store them privately in the following class implementation. When a button creates `IONServer` objects I initialize it with the function `-(void)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)pw` and pass it two `UITextField.text` strings.

If you notice in the init I am testing stuff with NSLog but at every breakpoint it seems like the `storedLogins` NSMutable array is `nil`.

**IONServer.m**

```
#import "IONServer.h"
#import "IONLoginResult.h"

@interface IONServer ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *storedLogins;

@end

@implementation IONServer

-(void)createStoredLogins
{
    NSArray *firstUser = @[@"user1",@"pass1"];
    NSArray *secondUser = @[@"user2",@"pass2"];

    [self.storedLogins addObject:firstUser];
    [self.storedLogins addObject:secondUser];

}

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self createStoredLogins];
        NSLog(@"Stored logins: %@", _storedLogins);
        NSLog(@"Stored user: %@", _storedLogins[0][0]);
    }
    return self;

}

-(void)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)pw
{
    NSArray *logins = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:_storedLogins];

    for (int i = 0; i < [logins count]; i++) {
        if (username == logins[i][0] && pw == logins[i][1]) {
            IONLoginResult *result = [[IONLoginResult alloc] initWithResult:YES errorMessage:@"Success!"];
            self.result = result;
            break;
        } else {
            IONLoginResult *result = [[IONLoginResult alloc] initWithResult:NO errorMessage:@"Error!"];
            self.result = result;
        }
    }
}

-(void)logout
{

}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, it is nil, because you're not assigning anything else to that variable; it starts nil, as all objective-C variables do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array:

```
-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _storedLogins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self createStoredLogins];
        NSLog(@"Stored logins: %@", _storedLogins);
        NSLog(@"Stored user: %@", _storedLogins[0][0]);
    }
    return self;

}
```

Comment: doh! That was it. Perfect!